# How to load an .dtbo file in beaglebone black with ubuntu distribution

Tags: beagleboneblack

I would like to known how to load the dtbo file to configure the pins in the beaglebone black for the linux ubuntu distribution -> (get from: https://rcn-ee.com/rootfs/2015-07-08/flasher/BBB-eMMC-flasher-ubuntu-14.04.2-console-armhf-2015-07-08-2gb.img.xz)

In this distro there's no /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.*/slots folder as used in many available tutorials.

Thanks advanced.

Comment: I am looking solution for the same problem. After few searches I could understand that capemgr is not available betond linux kernel 3.8. In Ubuntu 14.04, I could see the .dtb files in /boot/dtbs/4.1*** folder. I dont know how to get it loaded.

Comment: looks like they are still working on it. The BBIO library has not been updated yet. https://github.com/adafruit/adafruit-beaglebone-io-python/issues/80